# Accessing a method defined in the Superclass [Java]

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, polymorphism, extends

If I define 2 classes; one called Super, which has a method called potato(), and the second one, Sub, which extends Super.

I then declare an object of type Sub;

i.e Sub carrot;

within a third class/main within the same package.

Can I access the potato() method in this third class/main via carrot.potato()   ?

Comment: Can you please show us the code ? Answer depends on Access modifiers here.

Comment: I've simplified it down a fair bit so I don't have to worry about showing my code. What I've asked is fairly hypothetical, but imagine the potato() method is public.

Comment: @Agressive Yes, you can. If you use the correct Access modifiers as mentioned Suresh

Comment: `potato` is not a good name for a method (even for an example such as this).

Comment: @Zabri There is nothing wrong with the name `potato`. Unless you want to contend the sanity of a name such as `String#indexOf` or `Collection.stream`.

Comment: I keep getting this error when trying to do exactly what I described above: "Cannot make a static reference to a non-static method blabla from super". Why must the method be static if it's being accessed by an object of its own type?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Maybe it's individual. I don't wanna argue. It's just that I can't imagine a situation where `potato` would be appropriate for describing what a method does. Which is what I think a method name should do - shortly describe what the method does.

Comment: @zabri By convention it would have to *return a potato*. It is quite obvious.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Then I don't like this convention much and would always prefer something like `getPotato` or `toPotato`.

Comment: @Zabri Then it must be tough on you when you use the JDK :) Such is life...

Answer (score 2):

Sub extends Super. That means that sub is a super with some extra details. That means that you can treat sub exactly as a Super object. So carrot.potato() is correct.

Comment: Beautiful, that's exactly what I thought. However, I get this error when trying to do so: "Cannot make a static reference to a non-static method blabla from super". Why must the method be static if it's being accessed by an object of its own type?

Comment: @AggressiveSneeze. That means that you are not accessing the method from an *object*, but from a static method. That has nothing to do with inheritance, which your question seems to be about.

Comment: But I'm accessing it via (name of object of type sub).methodname(). Is that not correct?

Comment: Sorry I was thinking in Python code. If you're in a static code and you're trying to access another method in this class, it has to be static to. Except if you're using the method of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Since every Child **Is-A** Parent , you can access that method through Child as well. Assuming it is a public method(as you mentioned in the comments).

If you want to see what I mean in the first comment, [`have a look here.`](http://codeinventions.blogspot.com/2014/09/default-access-modifier-in-java-or-no.html)